# Resque: one worker per queue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque, ruby-1.9.2

I currently have a Rails 3.0 project, with Ruby 1.9.2 and Resque.

My application has multiple worker classes and multiple queues, that are dynamically created (during runtime). Also, there are multiple workers started that are free to work on any queues, because at start time there isn't any existing queues, and they cannot be predicted:

```
$ COUNT=3 QUEUE=* rake resque:workers
```

Queues a created based on the `project`'s id:

```
@queue = "project_#{project.id}".to_sym
```

For a given queue, their jobs have to processed in order and one at a time. My problem is that, by having multiple workers, multiple jobs are processed in parallel.

Is there a way to set the maximum number of workers per queue (to 1)? Is there a way to lock a queue while a job is processing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came to a quite simple solution using resque-retry and locks stored in redis (I am doing this for users, just do it for projects): https://stackoverflow.com/a/10933666/745266

Comment: Looks good @lacco, thanks! Your problem was really similar as mine, so I'll definitely take a look at your solution soon.

Answer (score 2):

Resque-pool can help you specify number of workers per queue.

https://github.com/nevans/resque-pool

Comment: Thanks Nick, but that doens't work for me, as my queues are created on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The first solution I thought of would be to check if there is any worker working in a given queue when there's another worker polling that same queue. This could be done by reimplementing `Resque::Job.reserve(queue)`:

```
module Resque
  class Job

    def self.reserve(queue)

      Resque::Worker.working.each do |worker|
        # if already working in the same queue
        if worker.job['queue'] == queue
          return
        end
      end

      return unless payload = Resque.pop(queue)
      new(queue, payload)
    end

  end
end
```

A possible issue would be the race condition. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you finally came to a solution, did the code work in production?

Comment: The solution turned out to be much more complicated than that and I decided to go with one worker only to guarantee my condition. Whenever performance becomes an issue, I will worry about it! :P